# Injecting properties on constructor

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have to consume a REST api which follows a common syntax across all retrievable objects:

baseUrl + domainObjectName + qualifier

E.g.
"http://myweb.com/api/" + "cities" + "/{id}"

I created a BaseDao for my data layer and I would like to set up in DAO instantiation the base url for each domain object (baseUrl + domainObjectName). The problem is I have my api Base url defined in the properties file (and would like to keep it that way), and it is not available in the DAO constructor.

This is what I have:

```
public abstract class BaseDao {

    protected static final String ID_QUALIFIER = "/{id}";
    protected String domainObjectName = "";
    protected String doBaseUrl = "";

    @Value("#{config['baseUrlRest']}")
    public String apiBaseUrl;

    public GenericDaoRestImpl(String domainObjectName) {
        this.domainObjectName = domainObjectName;
        this.doBaseUrl = apiBaseUrl + domainObjectName;
    }

}
```

When my dao is instantiated, apiBaseUrl is still null, although after creation it is indeed injecting the baseUrl property.

Is there any way around this, like injecting the property as a static constant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because Java doesn't allow to set fields of a class before the constructor is called. So Spring can't inject the value. There are two solutions:

1. Pass the value to the constructor instead (example 1)
2. Use `@PostConstruct` (example 2)

Example 1:

```
public GenericDaoRestImpl(
    @Value("#{config['baseUrlRest']}") String apiBaseUrl
    String domainObjectName
) {
    ...
}
```

Example 2:

```
@Value("#{config['baseUrlRest']}")
public String apiBaseUrl;

public GenericDaoRestImpl(String domainObjectName) {
    this.domainObjectName = domainObjectName;
}

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    this.domainObjectName = domainObjectName;
    this.doBaseUrl = apiBaseUrl + domainObjectName;
}
```

I prefer the `@PostConstruct` because constructor injection eventually leads to constructors with many parameters which makes them unwieldy.

If you don't like it, your third option is using the [builder pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) with a [fluent interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface).